# how to render json data in popup from .json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column",
      handle: ".portlet-header",
      cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
      placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
    });

    $( ".portlet" )
      .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

    $( ".portlet-toggle" ).click(function() {
      var icon = $( this );
      icon.toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick" );
      icon.closest( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });
  });











   $(function(json) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    console.log(json);

  });

$.getJSON("AnalyticsFoxMain.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console

    window.onload = function () {
    d3.json("data.json", function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
    console.log(json);

     $('#jsonImage').attr('src', json.image);
     $( '#jsonText'  ).text(json.Company);
     $('#jsonCde').text(json.Brand);
     $('#jsonDesc').text(json.Description);
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        title:{
            text: "sentiment"
        },
                animationEnabled: true,
        legend:{
            verticalAlign: "center",
            horizontalAlign: "left",
            fontSize: 12,
            fontFamily: "Helvetica"        
        },
        theme: "red and blue",
        data: [
        {        
            type: "pie",       
            indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",       
            indexLabelFontSize: 20,
            indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
            startAngle:-25,      
            showInLegend: true,
            toolTipContent:" {y}",
            dataPoints: [
                {  y: json.Sentiment.positive},
                { y: json.Sentiment.negative},

            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",
    {

        title: { 
            text: "Source" 
        }, 
        data: [ 
        { 
            type: "doughnut", 
            indexLabel: " {y}",
            toolTipContent: "{y}",
            dataPoints: [ 
                {  y: json.Source.facebook},
                { y: json.Source.twitter},
                { y: json.Source.mouthshut}
            ] 
        } 
        ] 
    });
    chart.render();





google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Dealer1',    3540  ],
          ['Dealer2',1320]

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'others'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
chart.render();



   $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Adjectives',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Adjectives',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Space Inside',       2000],

                ['Looks',   4000],
                ['Reliability',    3000],
                {
                    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                    y: 0.2,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    });
});

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "title": "petrol",
    "value": 3540
  }, {
    "title": "Diesel",
    "value": 1320
  } ],
  "titleField": "title",
  "valueField": "value",
  "labelRadius": 5,

  "radius": "42%",
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );



    }


    $(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 350
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Issues'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: 50,
                depth: 10
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [
                ['GearProblems', 4000],
                ['EngineKnocking', 2000],
                ['PowerWindows',3000]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
});
```

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
background: transparent;
}

html {

  margin:10px 200px 80px 80px;
  padding:1px ;
  background:white;
}





#content {
  text-align:center;

  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:120px 0 10px 0;

  width:200px;
  height:50px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{display:none;}

.checkbox:checked + .label{
  background:#7B7484;
  color:#231733;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .social {
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(-90px);
  -moz-transform:scale(1) translateY(-90px);
  -o-transform:scale(1) translateY(-90px);
  transform:scale(1) translateY(-90px);
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
}

.label {
  font-size:16px;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 10px;

  border-radius:100%;
  color:#7B7484;
}

.social {
  transform-origin:50% 0%;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  -moz-transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  -o-transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);
  transform:scale(0) translateY(-190px);

  opacity:0;
}
ul {
  position:bottom;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  color:#fff;
  height:46px;
  width:180px;
  background:#3B5998;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

ul li {
  font-size:20px;

  cursor:pointer;
  width:60px;
  margin:0;
  padding:12px 0;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  height:22px;}

ul li:hover {color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);}

ul:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:35px auto;
  height:0;
  width:0;

  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #3B5998;
}

li[class*="twitter"]


body {
  padding:105px;
  vertical-align: Centered;
  }

  .column {
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .portlet {
    margin: 0 1.2em 1em 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
  }

  .portlet-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
  }
  .portlet-content {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .portlet-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    height: 150px;
  }










/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 20px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}



#chartdiv {
    width       : 100%;
    height      : 435px;
    font-size   : 11px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<link href="css/leaf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


 <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
 <h1 style="color:blue; font-size:25pt">AUTOLYTICS </h1>
</center>
<div>
<table style="width:550; height:180 ">
<td>    
<img src="" id="jsonImage" style="width: 400px; height: 230px;" />
</td>
<td>
<div style="width:550px;height:200px;padding:1px;border:1px hidden; float:right">
    <strong>

<p id="jsonText" style="float:left;"></p>
     <p id="jsonCde" style="padding-left : 5px;float:left;"></p>
    </strong>
    <p id="jsonDesc" style="ALIGN:justify ;width: 500px; height: 110px;float:right "> </p>


    <button name="button" style="float: right;" >search</button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="eg.Mumbai" size= 55; style=" border:1px solid #ff0040;float:right " />

    </td>

</div>
</table>

</div>




<div>
<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Sentiment</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
    <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Source</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
         <div id="chartContainer1" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
 </div>


<div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Issues</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
    <div id="container1" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Adjectives</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
    <div id="container" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>  

 <div class="column">
  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Type</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
 <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">others</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dialog" title="popup">

</div>


 <footer>
 <div id="content">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="share" checked>
  <label for="share" class="label entypo-export"></label>
  <div class="social">
    <ul>
      <li class="entypo-twitter"></li>
      <li class="entypo-facebook"></li>
      <li class="entypo-gplus"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

This is my project,in this project how to getting data from .JSON file in  pop- window by using JavaScript.
In these code how to render data in popup window by using java-script,in these code multiple JSON files to render

Comment: Kindly post some html/CSS/JS of the project related to the problem....

Comment: $('#popup .body').html('<pre>'+JSON.stringify( yourObject )+'</pre>')

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON file can be retrieved by an url:

in your json file:

```
data = '[
    {"surname" : "Alex", "first_name" : "Chaosman"},
    {"surname" : "Ben", "first_name" : "Dickson"},]';
```

in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.json"></script>
<script>
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(arr[0].first_name + ' ' + arr[0].surname);
    console.log(arr[1].first_name + ' ' + arr[1].surname);
</script>
```